# Dynamic bootsrap 4 carousel with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a dynamic carousel, i was expecting to get the data from data.newer, from my database referred at my node.js server, and show it on the carousel, but it is not happening, the carousel doesn't appears on the page.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="firstcar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
                </div>
```

and the javascript (i'm placing it before the `</body>` closing tag of the document):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            for(let novo of data.newer) {
                $('<div class="carousel-item bg-carousel"><img class="d-block w-100 img-carousel" src="/img/'+novo.imagem_p+'"><div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"></div><p>'+novo.titulo+'</p></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            $('#firstcar').carousel();
            $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
```

After a really helpful comment, i've got a look at the dev console and found the following error: `jquery.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):42) at e (jquery.slim.min.js:2) at t (jquery.slim.min.js:2)` and the warning: `jQuery.Deferred exception: data is not defined`

the (index).42 on th error is referring to the line (which is at the javascript code of this question): `for(let novo of data.newer) {`

With this, i think the problem can be with: the way i'm using the `for` statement, or the way i'm tryng to get the data (like a wrong reference or something). For both of the possible problems i can't get a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What doesn't work? Telling us it doesn't work doesn't help. What are you expecting and what is happening? Are there any errors in your dev console? Also, you may want to consider moving your script right before the closing `</body>` tag, since - I'm guessing - that your script doesn't know that the `.carousel` element exists and you are getting an error.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. My expectation was to get the data from data.newer, from my database referred at my node.js server, and show it on the carousel, but it is not happening, the carousel doesn't appears.

Comment: Well, i'm new at coding and haven't thought about checking the dev console, so thanks for the instruction, i've got a look there and found the following error:
`jquery.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):42)
    at e (jquery.slim.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.slim.min.js:2)`
the `(index).42` on th error is referring to the line (which is at the question's javascript code):                 `for(let novo of data.newer) {`

Comment: With this, i think the problem can be with: the  way i'm using the `for` statement, or the way i'm tryng to get the data (like a wrong reference or something). For both of the possible problems i can't get the solution :/

Comment: By the way, the error that i mentioned occours with the script before the `</body>`, i've committed this change before adding these comments.